# undefined method `hello' for Gamification::User:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, module

I have a class inside `app/models/user.rb`:

```
class User
  include Gamification::User

  def self.hello
    puts "hello"
  end

end
```

I have a module inside `lib/gamification/user.rb`:

```
module Gamification
  module User
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods

    end
  end
end
```

I have another model ap/models/conversation.rb

```
class Conversation

    def hello
      User.hello
    end

end
```

`config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/tracker_related/**/"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/helpers/**/"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/concerns/**/"]
```

When I hit `Conversation.new.hello` then I expect it should print `"hello"`. But it returns:

```
undefined method `hello' for Gamification::User:Module.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This seems to be a naming conflict - when you call `User.new` inside your User class ruby takes the module `User` instead of class `User`. Try `::User.hello`

Comment: We are calling this method from multiple places. I cannot change this to each and every place. I have just added user module recently.

Comment: Any other way instead of appending :: to each call ?

Comment: still getting the same error after adding ::.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you add all the folders from the lib folder to your autoload path. When rails hit `User` constant for the first time it checks those folders for a file called `user.rb` before it checks default paths like `app/models`. Since such a file exists, it returns the class/module defined in it.

I don't think adding folders that way is the best practice (due to this issue). Try removing

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

and put

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/lib/"
```

This however will force you to use fully qualified constants names like `Gamification::User` instead of `User`.